# Basis for Kernel and Trace of Square Matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations, trace

I'm supposed to find the basis for the kernel and the image of $T$, and I know that $$T(A) = Tr(A)=\sum^n_{k=1}a_{kk}=a_{11}+\dots+a_{nn},$$ but to me it just look like  scalar.  I know that bases are supposed to consist of vectors that span whatever space or linear transformation your in, so would the basis $\beta_1$ for the kernel of $T$ be the entire map?  And, what about the basis $\beta_2$ for the image of $T$?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: the question is incomplete.

Comment: See my answer 

   
    URL = {https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2845131}
}

Comment: I'm a little confused. Can you make clearer what is your question?

Comment: My exact question is, "Find a basis for ker($T$) and for Im($T$)."

Comment: Then you are completely misunderstanding this problem. It says **nothing** about the "trace".  T is the linear transformation itself, not a "trace".  Given a linear transformation from vector space U to vector space V, the "kernel" is the subspace of U of all vectors, u, such that Tu= 0 and the "image" is the subspace of V of all vectors, v, such that Tu= v for some u in U.